# MMA7455 Output Values

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, accelerometer

I am currently playing around with my raspberry pi and bought an accelerometer. I want it to monitor the g-force levels in a car crash. I downloaded the data sheet for the the module and it says the the values are outputted in a single byte (0-255). I have been reading other articles online and they said if you want the raw values to be converted into g-force values then you simply multiple it by 0.016 (g-Range = 8g) however does this mean that the device can only detect movement just 4.1g and under?. I need a module that detect g-force levels of 20-50

Using this principle:

2g mode = 16g and below

4g mode = 8g and below

8g mode = 4g and below

Also if I configure the module in 2g mode would this mean it would be less accurate if I wanted to get reading say every 0.05 seconds?

Is there anyone who has any knowledge of using this accelerometer. Any help would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet is quite clear: in Ng mode you can measure +/-Ng.

So, depending on selected range, you will be able to measure up to 8g not 20-50g you need. And of course greater range means less precision.

About you calculation is 8g mode, the module has a 8bit output OR 10bit output for the 8g mode. 2^10*0.016 gives about 16. As the result is signed the range is +/-8g.

Comment: Does this mean I would need a different accelerometer to bee able to cope with higher g-force levels?

Comment: If you need to measure more than 8g, you will need a different accelerometer yes.